# Clicking on the custom component in sidebar should load on the same page

Tags: visualforce, javascript, sidebar

I have created a custom Html area component on the sidebar , which contains links which are linked to corresponding VF pages , how can i make it to load on the same page

Comment: can you be specific ?Like where the custom links need to be loaded ?

Comment: it should load on the same page where the custom component link is being clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that when you click on one of the links (which points to vf pages) on your custom sidebar component, you want the links to open up in the same main page. You could use the below javascript in your component to open the links in the same page:

```
top.location.href = '/apex/yourVfPage';
```

Comment: I think he want to load pages without have to reload the current page.

Comment: @mast0r: So you mean, when the user clicks on the links, the page should be rendered in the sidebar component and not refresh the main page? Anyways lets wait for the OP to comment, just to make sure :)

Comment: Not in the sidebar component but will be included into the page, like `reRender`.